# Open .txt in a new tab on Firefox instead of download by default

Tags: javascript, php, html, firefox, cross-browser

I am trying to open a new tab to display the content of a txt file when it's being clicked on. It works fine with Chrome and IE (for once) but not on Firefox.

So basically I added `target="_blank"` in my `<a></a>` tag in my `PHP` file:

```
<a class="log" onClick="event.stopPropagation()" style="float:Right;" href="http://localhost/report/Java/16/9/log/buildLog20170124090806‌​.txt" target="_blank">File</a>
```

On both Chrome and IE it opens in a new tab but **with Firefox, it downloads the file instead**. Response HTTP headers are:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 24 Jan 2017 09:48:51 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=79
Server: Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/5.6.28
Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=DRiYzQxODY5ZGNhZDBiYmI3YmE0Y2UzMzQzZWVmMWViNSJ9; expires=Tue, 24-Jan-2017 11:48:52 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.28
```

What can I do to force Firefox to open it in a new tab?

I used the same syntax for an HTML file within the same page and it works just fine.

Comment: What HTTP headers are you sending?

Comment: What do you imply by headers? What's in the `<head></head>` tag? Sorry I am new in this HTML world and I'm working on someone else's code...

Comment: In Firefox, hit Ctrl+Shift+Q. A new panel will open. When you load the link a new entry will show up. When you click on it, you'll see a new subpane that includes a "Response headers" block. These are the HTTP headers sent back by the web server, which can include information on how to deal with the file.

Comment: Here: `Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 24 Jan 2017 09:48:51 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=79
Server: Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/5.6.28
Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=DRiYzQxODY5ZGNhZDBiYmI3YmE0Y2UzMzQzZWVmMWViNSJ9; expires=Tue, 24-Jan-2017 11:48:52 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.28`

Comment: `Content-Length: 0`? Is the file supposed to be empty?

Comment: Actually I think that the headers I wrote are not the good ones. No line is added in the developper tools window when I click on the link...

Comment: Could it come from the `onClick="event.stopPropagation()"` maybe?

Comment: Nope. But it clearly reveals you have a lot of JavaScript code you hadn't even mentioned. Even the HTML you've finally shared is just a template, not the actual link. So it could be anything.

Comment: The generated link is `http://localhost/report/Java/16/9/log/buildLog20170124090806.txt`

Comment: Can't you just edit the question and show the full actual HTML? It's impossible to understand the problem with unformatted assorted code fragments scattered around comments. My guess so far is that you forgot the quotes around `href` but who knows.

Comment: I edited the question. The quotes are present around the href content

Comment: See also: [Force view text file instead of download in Firefox?](https://superuser.com/q/43379/91971) or [this content-disposition header answer focused on PHP](https://superuser.com/a/991492/91971).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to open it with Javascript

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('text.txt', '_blank');">...</a>
```

Comment: This solution doesn't change anything I'm afraid.

Comment: It works for me, actually both possibilities work for me  
-`<a href='Scripts/text.txt' target="_blank">Link 1</a>`  
-`<a href="#" onclick="window.open('text.txt', '_blank');">Link 2</a>`

Comment: @bendajo — If you can't reproduce the problem with the original code, then you don't have much reason to think that your code would make a difference. It doesn't make a difference for you.

Comment: @Quentin I did not think about that, I am sorry and thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Looks file the `<a>` tag is incorrect. `<a>` doesnt have a `src` attribute.

```
<a target="_blank" src="/path/to/file.txt">Download</a>
```

**Use this instead :**

```
<a target="_blank" href="/path/to/file.txt">Download</a>
```

And with the different behaviour in different browsers its nothing to do with

`target="_blank"` ***that part is correct***.

Just the path is the one causing issue.

Use the follwing code to understand better.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<a target="_blank" href="C:/Users/sshetty1/Desktop/popup.txt">Download</a>
</body>
</html>
```

This code works with IE and Chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<a target="_blank" href="/C:/Users/sshetty1/Desktop/popup.txt">Download</a>
</body>
</html>
```

This works for Chrome and Firefox and not for IE.

The difference is just because the path ***( / before the C:)***

"**C:**/Users/sshetty1/Desktop/popup.txt" and

"**/C:**/Users/sshetty1/Desktop/popup.txt"

Its the way each browser understands the system path.

***Note : Change the path according to your system and run the sample.***

Comment: Thanks for the help but it's not working. First, I am already using `href` and not `src`. And second, my bad I didn't mention it, the file is a `PHP` file.

Comment: Instead, never load "files". Have an actual server running, and load URLs. Also, even if you _were_ using files, you'd need the `file:///` protocol, which immediately locks the browser down to an incredible degree.